# How can I return boxed value?

Tags: rust, heap-memory

I basically have a function that creates some object which need to be allocated on the heap. What I want to do is return from that function a structure containing a reference to that heap-allocated value.

```
struct Cont<'a> {
    pub v: &'a i32
}

impl<'a> Cont<'a> {
    fn new(v: &'a i32) -> Cont {
        Cont {
            v: v
        }
    }
}

fn f<'a>() -> Cont<'a> {
    let v = Box::new(6);

    Cont::new(&v)
}

fn main() {
    let c = f();

    println!("{}", c.v);
}
```

I'm getting `error: 'v' does not live long enough`.

You can find the example [here](http://is.gd/R9Ps1d).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot return a structure that only contains a borrowed pointer to your object, because your `Box` would be destroyed at the end of the function.

You need to transfer ownership of the `Box` out of the function so that the heap-allocated object remains alive. The simplest way to do this is to move the `Box` into your struct:

```
struct Cont {
    pub v: Box<i32>
}

impl Cont {
    fn new(v: Box<i32>) -> Cont {
        Cont {
            v: v
        }
    }
}

fn f() -> Cont {
    let v = Box::new(6);
    Cont::new(v)
}

fn main() {
    let c = f();

    println!("{}", c.v);
}
```

If you want a struct that is able to store either a borrowed pointer or an owning `Box` (or other kinds of smart pointers), we can make it generic over the [`Borrow`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) trait.

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

struct Cont<T> where T: Borrow<i32> {
    pub v: T
}

impl<T> Cont<T> where T: Borrow<i32> {
    fn new(v: T) -> Cont<T> {
        Cont {
            v: v
        }
    }
}

fn owned() -> Cont<Box<i32>> {
    let v = Box::new(6);
    Cont::new(v)
}

fn borrowed(v: &i32) -> Cont<&i32> {
    Cont::new(v)
}

fn main() {
    let c = owned();
    println!("{}", c.v);

    let x = 123;
    let c = borrowed(&x);
    println!("{}", c.v);
}
```

Comment: What if I want to also use references in the `struct`?

Comment: Do you mean that sometimes you want the struct to just borrow a value, and sometimes to own the value?

Comment: I don't want to borrow. I may have some `&value` created in a function and some `Cont`s created and used afterwards without returning any of them or actually passing them further down. So then `&value` would make sense because I don't want to allocate that on the heap. Is there a way to use either a `Box` or a `Ref`?

Comment: For example: in a function create `value`, send `&value` to `Cont`, have some `Cont` method return some `i32`, return that `i32` from this function.

Comment: I've added another solution to my answer.

Comment: Because when you drop a `Cont<Box<i32>>`, you need to free the heap-allocated memory (which is done automatically by the compiler), while dropping a `Cont<&i32>` doesn't need that. You could do something similar with an `enum` instead, if you know exactly what kinds of pointers you need to handle, but if you were making a library, maybe some users would like to use `Rc<i32>` or even a custom smart pointer, and the generic approach works well for this, but not the `enum` approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103206/discussion-between-dragostis-and-francis-gagne).